# MS ACCESS - Query Criteria based on two Textbox

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I need to make a search box that could reach and take any field, since I know about nothing of VBA, I did it by using queries...

I have a query with this OR criteria in each field (properly done in there):

`Like "*" & [txtbox1] & "*" Or Like "*" & [txtbox2] & "*"`

Problem is: 
it's not working as intended...

If I type nothing on either box1 or box2, it shows all... even when, say, I type something I know is on one field and in the other something from another field then it shows still a lot it shouldn't show...

I wanted it to filter by the first, and then that results by the other one... only show result that meet both criteria (when I type in both txtboxes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it needs to match both textbox1 and textbox2 you should use an AND instead of the OR

```
Like "*" & [txtbox1] & "*" And Like "*" & [txtbox2] & "*"
```

Ok, based on your comment I'm guessing you are using the query designer, I'm not sure how this can be done using the desginer, this can be done using SQL so a basic query

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE (field1 like "*" & [txtbox1] & "*" OR field2 like "*" & [txtbox1] & "*" ....for all the required columns) 
AND (field1 like "*" & [txtbox2] & "*" OR field2 like "*" & [txtbox2] & "*" ....for all the required columns)
```

Comment: you see... It more like one or the other... as it's searching around the whole table I could type something to find anything... usually I would first search for one thing and then filter those results with the second box... and for that... the first box usually will be for one field and the other for another

Comment: I also tried using IIF conditions (gave an error for too complex or something like that) and using different lines for each box (that ended up the same thing as the "or" one I posted...)